# awk -v bailing out / cannot open file because of variables in the replace field

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to input a string containing variables above the nth match of a pattern using awk (for the moment). My actual goal is to modify the content of the real_printf.c file by adding lines just above the 2nd match of `return (0);` containing for instance `printf("%s%d%s", str00,int01,str03);`. I am creating a random printf generator as a self-imposed bonus for a school project (-> recoding printf in .c) and can already input random variables declaration, transform flags between `%` and the conversion indicator, among other things. It's the final step before I get to have a working prototype.

**I already have the awk command for the match of `return (0);` but I faced a first bug saying I was dividing by 0 and thus ending awk execution. See code below:**

1)`awk '/return/{c++;if(c==2){ print "\t\tprintf("'$input_pf'", '$var_name');"; c=1 }} 1' .annex/real_printf.c`

**I corrected this bug by changing the code above into the code below, after having read many online resources, by using awk -v and declaring variables:**

2)`awk -v input="$input_pf" name="$var_name" "/return/{c++;if(c==2){ print "\\t\\tprintf\(\"$input\", $name\);"; c=1 }} 1" .annex/real_printf.c`

**For the above code, the shell returned this error:**

```
awk -v input=%p name=ptr00 '/return/{c++;if(c==2){ print \t\tprintf("",' ')'
awk: can't open file /return/{c++;if(c==2){ print \t\tprintf("",
 source line number 1
+ '; c=1 }} 1' .annex/real_printf.c
.annex/modify/pct_conv.sh: line 34: ; c=1 }} 1: command not found
```

**So I decided to remove the double-quotes around the variables following awk -v, see code below.**

3) `awk -v input=$input_pf name=$var_name "/return/{c++;if(c==2){ print "\\t\\tprintf\(\"$input\", $name\);"; c=1 }} 1" .annex/real_printf.c`

**I now get the following result and am short of ideas to try:**

```
awk -v input=%f%o%s name=f00,o01,str02 '/return/{c++;if(c==2){ print \t\tprintf("",' ')'`
`awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     ``>>> name=f00,o01, <<<``
awk: bailing out at source line 1
+ '; c=1 }} 1' .annex/real_printf.c
.annex/modify/pct_conv.sh: line 34: ; c=1 }} 1: command not found
```

It should be a syntax problem, or a I might be asking too much from awk in one single line. Maybe awk isn't even the best tool for this matter. I tried with `sed -i '' 's/return (0);/printf("$input_pf", $var_name)/2'` in order to get to the 2nd match of my pattern but it wouldn't have worked neither.

How would you proceed with this problem ?

Comment: The double quotes are shell syntax -- awk doesn't see them at all, but they're necessary for the shell to do the right thing with all possible values (including values with spaces, values that can expand as globs, etc).

Comment: Also, note that you need a separate `-v` before *each* `name=value` assignment, and you should use only single quotes (never double quotes) around the awk code itself.

Comment: Note btw, that we need an input file we can run this with to have a proper [mcve] -- code we can run ourselves to observe whether/when a fix is working.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy because I just have 1 possible match after the first check. Not a global solution but works in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# assign some values so we can test
input_pf=%f%o%s
var_name=f00,o01,str02

# sample input to exercise the code
input=$(cat <<'EOF'
return
return
return
return
EOF
)

# actual code here
awk -v input="$input_pf" -v name="$var_name" '
/return/ {
  if(count++ > 0) {
    printf "\t\tprintf(\"%s\", %s);\n", input, name
  }
}
1 { print }' <<<"$input"
```

Note:

- We're putting a separate `-v` before each `name=value` pair. Without this, the second `name=value` pair is treated as your awk script, and the argument after it is treated as an input file name.
- We're *always* quoting the shell expansions in double quotes.
- We're putting the awk code in *single* quotes, so it isn't mangled by a shell.
- We *aren't* using `$` when referring to awk variables (since that's shell syntax only).

With those changes, the above correctly (as far as I can tell, with no sample input or output given in the question) returns:

```
return
        printf("%f%o%s", f00,o01,str02);
return
        printf("%f%o%s", f00,o01,str02);
return
        printf("%f%o%s", f00,o01,str02);
return
```

Comment: What you wrote, using the `printf` function and adding the `{ print }` at the end made it work ! Many thanks.

Comment: The `{ print }` shouldn't really make a difference -- it's the default action, so it's what the `1` should do by default; I just added it for clarity, so people who don't know how/why the `1` at the end works can more easily understand the code. (That's the same reason I prefer code with whitespace and indentation over one-liners).